# SQL SERVER AGENT

Tags: sql-server

This is the error i m getting when i try to start the SQL AGENT windows could not start the SQL server Agent(SQLEXPRESS)service on local computer. Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly

Comment: What have you tried or looked at? This typically occurs when the account the agent is logging on with does not have credentials to authenticate and start the service. I'm guessing but can you go to the windows event viewer and look for a more specific error?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Agent is not available in SQLEXPRESS.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-supported-features-for-sql-server-2016